# Realtek audio driver loop

Tags: audio, drivers

I have not been able to identify the cause.

Out of nowhere, my audio would just be dead and restarting without reinstalling realtek will just give me the "speaker with red x".

No realtek detected in device manager.
No realtek settings in control panel.

OS: Windows 10 64 bit
Hardware: Dell XPS 9550

Comment: Which operating system? What hardware? There isn't enough information for an answer.

Comment: sorry bout that, edited.